# WPF Bing Maps Control with WMS leayer

Tags: wpf, bing-maps, wms

Does anyone know if I'm able to use WMS layer and put it on Bing Maps Control in WPF application ?

Here is my WMS: http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/pub/guest/G2_GO_WMS/MapServer/WMSServer

This topic is so unknown for me, that any help and explanation will be great. Thanks

Comment: If your WMS would support EPSG:3857, I could tell you how to show it with my [XAML MapControl](https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/).

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator

Comment: It seems that they support it

Comment: Right now it doesn't. I made a GetCapabilities request (by adding `?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities` to the base URL), and there's no layer supporting EPSG:3857, or the equivalent EPSG:900913.

Comment: Ah, it seems you are right. I was looking for the wrong thing. Anyway, your answear solves my problem, because if this WMS doesn't support WSG84, it's impossible to use it in the Bing Maps also. Thank you for your time

Comment: It supports `CRS:84` which also uses WGS84 as ellipsoid. Do not confuse the ellipsoid (or "datum") with the projection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample that does this with the WP8.1 control. It shouldn't be overly difficult to port this over to the WPF control: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/adding-opacity-and-wms-support-to-tile-layers-in-wp8-1-maps/ Both support creating custom tile sources. Here is another blog post that uses custom tile sources in WPF: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/08/24/local-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-wpf/